# automate test for mediatR in dot net

Tags: c#, mediatr

hi guys I want write unit test for structure of MediatR.after search on internet I found that there is nothing library for this one.
How can I test it? (unit test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what testing framework is being used, and I hope this might help.

But with NUnit, you can try something like this using the MediatR NuGet package. The code below needs to be in the test setup.

```
public static async Task<TResponse> SendAsync<TResponse>(IRequest<TResponse> request)
{
    using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();    
    var mediator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISender>();    
    return await mediator.Send(request);
}
```

And then in the unit test just use:

```
  await this.SendAsync(commandThatNeedsToBeSent);
```

You can clean up the method body, by using the resolve to get the service. Found a repository that might be really neat. All credit goes to the author of the repository.

https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/tests/Application.IntegrationTests/Testing.cs

Comment: Hope I understood the question correctly.